# can read only first line of file php

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I want to read a .tsv file that comes from an input. But only can get the first line.

dd($request->file) returns this:

```
  -test: false
  -originalName: "ürünler_2021-04-08_02-39-00.tsv"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "php1D74.tmp"
  basename: "php1D74.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php1D74.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php1D74.tmp"
  aTime: 2021-04-09 05:08:47
  mTime: 2021-04-09 05:08:47
  cTime: 2021-04-09 05:08:47
  inode: 10133099161895727
  size: 1987
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php1D74.tmp"
}
```

and use fgets() with loop but all I can get is first line

```php
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|max:2048',
        ]);            

        $file = fopen($request->file, "r");
        
        if ($file) {         
             while (($line = fgets($file))) {
               dd($line);
            }   
            fclose($file);
        }
```

It happens because I try to read a .tsv file?

Comment: can't you use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dd($line) will run dump() and then die(). That is why you only get the first line.

If you want to dump the content of all lines, switch to just dump($line).

Comment: if you want to dump... use `dump()`

Comment: Yes, correct =) I forgott that Laravel has a helper function for var_dump(). 
I have updated my answer.